# Using Wordpress API to mass update posts freezes the server

Tags: api

Our site has recently been infected and a malware code was added to all the 5300+ posts. I wrote a simple app using Wordpress PCL to update the texts of all posts. But after updating a couple hundreds of them, the server freezes completely and I have to do a hard reset of the VPS. I am not versed in web technologies, so I have no idea how to investigate and solve this.

Comment: what is the WordPress PCL? Is that a plugin? Are you referring to https://github.com/wp-net/WordPressPCL? You mentioned you wrote a simple app to update text but you didn't share any code or what the code does. It's also not clear if you're adding sleep/wait commands between actions to let the server catch up, or if these are all separate requests. As for the VPS freezing up that's a little beyond WordPress, it's most likely an overloaded database server

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. I'm donig a foreach loop on downloaded posts and add a 300 ms delay between iterations. So, could you be so kind to advise where to go further from here?

Comment: Yes to which? At least increase the 300ms timeout and do performance benchmarking of the server side API requests. If your database freezes up and crashes under load in such a way that the entire VPS needs power cycling that is a MariaDB/MySQL problem not a WordPress problem. There is no PHP based solution to a database crash other than doing less database heavy work. Note that there is no information about queries or code in your question, so if each iteration involves a heavy expensive operation such as a meta query etc then that is invisible to me and other viewers

Comment: I'm also concerned that this question may be too localised and generic to answer here. Please use the `edit` link to expand your question to add as much information as you can. Remember this isn't a discussion forum/message-board so your question must be self contained and have everything needed to write an answer

Comment: I will update the post as soon as I have the time

Answer (score 0):

This guy here got the following results doing something like "If you are importing a high volume of posts, go make a cup of tea. For this tutorial, I have created around ~1600 dummy posts. The progress bar below is up to 429/1600 after 4 minutes. It took around 15 minutes to complete the 1600 dummy test posts to write to the database via the API."  https://chrisleverseo.com/t/python-script-to-bulk-upload-new-wordpress-posts-from-a-csv-file-using-wordpress-rest-api.93/